# How to get serialized column list on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm user of Ruby on Rails.

I made active model like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id

  serialize :user_info, Hash
  serialize :user_auth, Array
  serialize :user_addr
end
```

I want to get the column names which contains a serialized object and type.

I'm looking forward to the method like this.

```
ex ) 
User.serialized_columns #=> {:user_info => Hash, :user_auth => Array, :user_addr => nil}
```

Would you help me?

Comment: Just curious to know, why do you want all the serialized columns?

Comment: just for my curiosity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get it using the method `serialized_attributes` which returns a `Hash` where key is the column name and value is the class of the column

So, you can get the serialized columns as

```
User.serialized_attributes
```

But you have modify the value of each key according to your requirement.